# How to combine multiple XML Files with XQuery

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery

I have 4 XML Files (file1.xml, file2.xml, file3.xml, file4.xml) with almost similar structure but different data. I am working on XQuery to perform different tasks but first I need to combine these XML files with XQuery. Please tell me how can I combine these files with XQuery. Here is my XQuery code which I write for file1.xml

```
<html>
<body>
<table border='1'>
<tr><td>Target</td><td>Successor</td></tr>

{

for $x in doc("file1.xml")//u//s//w
where lower-case(normalize-space($x))="has"
order by $x
return <tr><td>{data($x)}</td>
           <td>{data($x/following-sibling::w[1])}</td>
       </tr>

}

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, you could build a collection of these files, depending on your XQuery processor. Or you could simply use `for $x in (doc("file1.xml"), doc("file2.xml"), doc("file3.xml"), doc("file4.xml"))//u//s//w` in your query to process `w` elements of all four files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your XQuery implementation, there might be other ways to do this, but simply opening all of them and combining their contents should work pretty much all of the time:

```
for $x in (doc("file1.xml"), doc("file2.xml"), doc("file3.xml"))//u//s//w
```

For reasons of readability it might be more reasonable to factor out the document access (also if you need to access this set of files again):

```
let $files := (doc("file1.xml"), doc("file2.xml"), doc("file3.xml"))
for $x in $files//u//s//w
```